# Synchronization riddle with std::memory_order and three threads

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

Here is a problem about the `std::memory_order` rules in C++11, when it comes to three threads. Say, one thread **producer** saves a value and sets a flag. Then, another thread **relay** waits for this flag before setting another flag. Finally, a third thread **consumer** waits for the flag from **relay**, which should signal that `data` is ready for **consumer**.

Here is a minimal program, in the style of the examples in the C++ reference (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order):

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>

std::atomic<bool> flag1 = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);
std::atomic<bool> flag2 = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);
int data;

void producer()
{
  data = 42;
  flag1.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}

void relay_1()
{
  while (!flag1.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
    ;
  flag2.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}

void relay_2()
{
  while (!flag1.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst))
    ;
  flag2.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}

void relay_3()
{
  while (!flag1.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
    ;
  // Does the following line make a difference?
  data = data;
  flag2.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}

void consumer()
{
  while (!flag2.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
    ;
  assert(data==42);
}

int main()
{
  std::thread a(producer);
  std::thread b(relay_1);
  std::thread c(consumer);
  a.join(); b.join(); c.join();
}
```

#### Comments:

1. The first function `relay_1()` is insufficient and can trigger the `assert` in **consumer**. According to the C++ reference cited above, the `memory_order_acquire` keyword “ensures that all writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are visible in the current thread”. So, the `data=42` is visible to **relay** when it sets `flag2`. It sets it with `memory_order_release`, which “ensures that all writes in the current thread are visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable”. However, `data` has not been touched by **relay**, so the **consumer** might see memory accesses in a different order, and `data` may be uninitialized when **consumer** sees `flag2==True`.
2. The same argument applies to the stricter memory orderings in `relay_2()`. The sequentially-consistent ordering implies that “the synchronization is established between all atomic operations tagged `std::memory_order_seq_cst`”. However, that doesn't say anything about the variable `data`.

   Or do I understand something wrong here and `relay_2()` is sufficient?
3. Let's resolve the situation by accesses to `data` as in `relay_3()`. Here, the line `data = data` implies that `data` is read after `flag1` went to `true`, and the **relay** thread writes into `data`, before it sets `flag2`. Hence, the **consumer** thread must see the correct value.

   However, this solution seems a little strange. The line `data = data` seems something that a compiler would (in sequential code) immediately optimize out.

   Does the dummy line do the trick here? Any better way to achieve synchronization across three threads with the C++11 `std::memory_order` features?

By the way, this is not an academic question. Imagine that `data` is a big block of data instead of a single integer, and the *i*-th thread needs to pass on the information to the (*i*+1)-th thread up to which element the data has been processed by all threads with index ≤*i*.

#### Edit:

After reading Michael Burr's answer it is clear that `relay_1()` is sufficient. Please read his post for a completely satisfying solution to the problem. The C++11 standard gives stricter guarantees than what can be inferred from the cppreference.com web site alone. Therefore, consider the argumentation in Michael Burr's post as authoritative, not my comments above. The way to go is to establish an “inter-thread happens-before” relation (which is transitive) between the events in question.

Comment: To be fair, cppreference mentions transitivity of release-acquire synchronization a couple paragraphs later.

Comment: It wasn't so much the paragraph about transitivity that created my question. (That also doesn't seem right, though. I believe there is a typo: paragraph “Release-Acquire ordering”, bullet point “The synchronization is transitive”, second bullet from there: “Thread _B_ consumes atomic variable _a_.” should be “Thread _B_ **acquires** atomic variable _a_.”) It was more the definition of _acquire_ and _release_ on cppreference which, as I interpret it, gives weaker guarantees than the reasoning and quotes from the C++11 standard in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that `relay_1()` is sufficient to pass the value `42` from the producer to the consumer through `data`.

To show this, first I'll give single-letter names to the operations of interest:

```
void producer()
{
    /* P */ data = 42;
    /* Q */ flag1.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}

void relay_1()
{
  while (/* R */ !flag1.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
    ;

  /* S */ flag2.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
}


void consumer()
{
  while (/* T */ !flag2.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
    ;
  /* U */ assert(data==42);
}
```

I'm going to use the notation `A -> B` to mean that "A inter-thread happens before B" (C++11 1.10/11).

I argue that `P` is a visible side-effect with respect to `U` because:

- `P` is sequenced before `Q`, `R` is sequenced before `S`, and `T` is sequenced before `U` (1.9/14)
- `Q` synchronizes with `R`, and `S` synchronizes with `T` (29.3/2)

All of the next points are supported by the definition of "inter-thread happens before" (1.10/11):

- `Q -> S`  since the standard says "A inter-thread happens before an evaluation B if ... for some evaluation X, A synchronizes with X and X is sequenced before B" (`Q` synchronizes with `R` and `R` is sequenced before `S`, so `Q -> S`)
- `S -> U` following similar logic (`S` synchronizes with `T` and `T` is sequenced before `U`, so `S -> U`)
- `Q -> U` because `Q -> S` and `S -> U` ("A inter-thread happens before an evaluation B if ... A inter-thread happens before X and X inter-thread happens before B")

And finally,

- `P -> U` because `P` is sequenced before `Q` and `Q -> U` ("A inter-thread happens before an evaluation B if ... A is sequenced before X and X inter-thread happens before B")

Since `P` inter-thread happens before `U`, `P` happens before `U` (1.10/12) and `P` is a "visible side-effect" with respect to `U` (1.10/13).

`relay_3()` is also sufficient because the `data=data` expression is irrelevant.

And for the purpose of this producer/consumer problem, `relay_2()` is at least as good as `relay_1()` because in a store operation `memory_order_seq_cst` is a release and in a load operation `memory_order_seq_cst` is an acquire  (See 29.3/1). So the exact same logic can be followed.  Operations using `memory_order_seq_cst` have some additional properties having to do with how all `memory_order_seq_cst` are sequenced among other `memory_order_seq_cst` operations, but those properties don't come into play in this example.

I think that `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release` would not be very useful for implementing higher level synchronization objects if there weren't a transitive behavior such as this.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comprehensive answer! That not only solves the problem at hand completely but was also very illuminating for understanding how to argue about concurrency in general.